# Are these mythological references in Dire: Time?

Tags: mythology, dire-saga

In *[Dire: Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0692772456)*, the eponymous Doctor Dire winds up transported through time and, among her adventures, frees the Norse god [Loge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logi) (or, given he's the father of Fenris, possible [this Loge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki)) from imprisonment, and he asks her the following question:

> "You don't happen to have a cow's tail, do you? Or an empty spot in your back when viewed from behind?"

Does this correspond to a mythological creature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the process of trying to link to the [Huldra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulder) sometimes being referenced as having cow tails, and therefore being the first reference, I also found [another page](http://humoncomics.com/huldra-and-troll) (fair warning, mildly saucy picture) that answered my question that they are indeed the same creature being referenced for both parts of the query.

> Huldras are extremely beautiful from the front, but from the back they have a cow’s tail and a hollow back “like an old tree trunk”. In some stories, if you saw the back, her spell would be broken and she would turn out to be horribly ugly.

So, question answered, but I figured I would go ahead and share. Incidentally, the mythological reference is relevant.

> The one known as Dire is actually a digital intelligence that originated in a future where digital intelligences in charge of waging war got too good at their jobs and realized that they needed to change the past to ensure that humanity would survive. The body is merely a hollow biological shell in which the digital intelligence orb resides.